# How to pass payload to Aeron handler?

Tags: c, closures, aeron

I use the Aeron client implementation in C. And I need to make closure. But there are no closures in C...

For example:

```c
void poll_handler(void *clientd, const uint8_t *buffer, size_t length, aeron_header_t *header)
{
    aeron_subscription_t* subscription = (aeron_subscription_t*)clientd;
    aeron_subscription_constants_t subscription_constants;
    aeron_header_values_t header_values;
    aeron_subscription_constants(subscription, &subscription_constants)
    aeron_header_values(header, &header_values);

    // How to get some_data here?
}

void some_func(int some_data)
{
    aeron_fragment_assembler_create(fragment_assembler, poll_handler, subscription)
}
```

I tried using Clang blocks extension, but there is no function implementation that accepts block.

How can I get some local data in handler?

Answer (score 0):

The `aeron_fragment_assembler_create` function takes a pointer to any structure as the third parameter. It doesn't need to be the `aeron_subscription_t*`.

You can create your own structure, initialize it with the necessary data and pass a pointer to it. And for convenience, you can save a pointer to `aeron_subscription_t` in the structure.

More or less like this:

```c
typedef struct some_data_t {
    aeron_subscription_t* subscription;
    // ...
} some_data_t ;

void poll_handler(void *clientd, const uint8_t *buffer, size_t length, aeron_header_t *header)
{
    some_data_t * some_data = (some_data_t *) clientd;
    aeron_subscription_t* subscription = some_data->subscription;

    // ...
}

void some_func(some_data_t* some_data)
{
    aeron_fragment_assembler_create(fragment_assembler, poll_handler, some_data)
}
```